# Android ViewPager padding/margin between page fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Android Market/Google Music seem to be able to have a gap of some sort between the different fragments that are contained in the `ViewPager`.

Any idea how this is done? Adding margin/padding to the actual fragment view doesn't work, because the view still needs to occupy the entire width of the screen. The 'gap' is only visible when swiping the ViewPager.

Answer (score 128):

In [Support Package, r4](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) you can use these methods:

```
setPageMargin(int marginPixels)
setPageMarginDrawable(Drawable)
setPageMarginDrawable(int)
```

in [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) class.

I don't know why this doesn't have equivalent in XML :-(

If you need use dip unit you can use this method:

```
public static int convertDip2Pixels(Context context, int dip) {
    return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: For dp to px conversion, I prefer the cleaner Context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(int dimenId) method.

Comment: getting resource not found when executing Context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(int dimenId).

The ID of teh dimension is correct but it doesnt work

Comment: use adapter reference instead of Context

Answer (score 24):

Hoping this might help someone with a **ViewPager** and page margins.

I wanted to have a **ViewPager** is a **CardView** and had issues with the padding and the margin between the viewpager pages. The setPageMargin did not work for me at all. I had to use the following:

```
int pagerPadding = 16;
pager.setClipToPadding(false);
pager.setPadding(pagerPadding, 0, pagerPadding, 0);
```

This allow the pages to be very close together.

[image: Example of the viewpager with a small margin between the pages.]

Answer (score 7):

```
  viewPager.setPageMargin(dpToPx(10)); 
  // replace 10 with the value you want for margin in dp. 


 public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This .

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.h_view_pager);
    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setPadding(60, 0, 60, 0);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(20);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

pager.setClipToPadding(false);
pager.setPadding(left,0,right,0);
If you need space between two pages in the viewpager then add
pager.setPageMargin(int);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    viewPager.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample solution :

implement the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` in your activity or your fragment where you use the `ViewPager`

```
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();

        for (int i=0 ; i < tabStripChildCount ; i++){
            View view = mTabStrip.getChildAt(i);

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(0, 0, 50, 0);
            view.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

mTabStrip is the table layout in your activity or fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_activity__fragment_tab_viewer, container, false);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager); 
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mTabStrip = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    return view;
}
```

finally you will have a margin between your title fragments