# Viewpager having default left and right padding

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am designing a first run experience for my app using a Viewpager. It should show 3 images one by one when the user swipes. But I am getting a white space on the left and right edges when the image is shown. I want my images in the viewpager to take the full space. Please help.

Comment: please, post some snippet code!

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343487/android-viewpager-padding-margin-between-page-fragments

Comment: Giving negative left right margin worked for me. Thanks anyways.