# ViewPager - show margins of left and right fragments on the sides of current fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager

I need to show the margins of the left and right fragments of the current fragment on a ViewPager (design attached).

can it be done?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you need to use fragments? May be recyclerview is appropriate here?

Answer (score 0):

At first look at this answer. It help`s me once:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7972980/4516895

And also check this guide:
http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: I'll look into the multiple-viewpager. it looks like what I need. Thanks!