# how to show a part of next image in daimajia slider?

Tags: android, androidimageslider

I'm using daimajia slider library.

But I need to show part of prev, next images.

It looks like this.

[image]

I can't find options.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this UI, you can

**Option 1:** Use `ViewPager` and set paddings for it (You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33767806/4224024))

**Option 2:** When you have too many images to show and want to recycle -> Use horizontal `RecyclerView` with `SnapHelper` (You can check [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8))

Comment: wow...I saw this comment after fixing it with the second option. I think it's a great way.